# ExpressJS - Using local files in development and files from Azure Blob Storage in production

Tags: node.js, azure, express, gulp, azure-blob-storage

I am planning on re-building an application on express, which contains static assets which are retrieved from azure blob storage. What is the easiest way to switch the references in my jade files and Sass so when working locally/development, express looks for local assets and when pushed to production it looks for assets from azure?

I am using Gulp for my build process, so would it be better to do it within the build, or direct in the application as a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming both environments (prod and testing/development) are both Linux for the purposes of this answer.

In the environments running your express services, you can execute the below, which will allow express to understand which environment it is running in. This will save the status across reboots. Replace the "production" with whichever environment the service is running on that machine (development/production/testing/etc).

```
$ echo export NODE_ENV=production >> ~\.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now, within your app.js file, you may be able to configure your application references by modifying the below snippets:

```
app.configure('development', function() {
    // Set an application variable to use local resources
});

app.configure('production', function() {
    // Set an application variable to use Azure Blob Storage
});
```